# How do we get the last relation?

Tags: derivatives, physics, classical-mechanics

I am looking at the conservation of momentum.

The force at $W$ from the tensions at the boundary $\partial{W}$ is $$\overrightarrow{S}_{\partial{W}}=-\int_{\partial{W}}p \cdot \overrightarrow{n}dA=-\int_{W}\nabla p dV$$ where $p(\overrightarrow{x}, t)$ the pressure and $\overrightarrow{n}$ the unit perpendicular vector.

The massive forces is $$\overrightarrow{B}_{W}=\int_{W}\rho \overrightarrow{b}dV$$ where $\overrightarrow{b}$ the density of massive forces.

So, the total force on the fluids in the volum $W$ is $$\overrightarrow{S}_{\partial{W}}+\overrightarrow{B}_{W}=\int_{W}( \rho \overrightarrow{b}-\nabla p)dV$$

From the second Newton's law we have that $\overrightarrow{F}=m\cdot \overrightarrow{a}$ and since $m=\int \rho dV$ and $\overrightarrow{a}=\frac{D\overrightarrow{u}}{Dt}$, where $\frac{D}{Dt}$ the material derivative, we have the following:

$$\int_{W}\rho \frac{D\overrightarrow{u}}{Dt}dV=\overrightarrow{S}_{\partial{W}}+\overrightarrow{B}_{W}=\int_{W}(\rho \overrightarrow{b}-\nabla p)dV$$

The differential form of the conservation of momentum is $$\rho \frac{D\overrightarrow{u}}{Dt}=-\nabla p+\rho\overrightarrow{b}$$

We are looking for the integral form of the conservation of momentum.

We have $$\rho \frac{\partial{\overrightarrow{u}}}{\partial{t}}=-\rho (\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \nabla )\overrightarrow{u}-\nabla p+\rho \overrightarrow{b}$$

From the differential form of the conservation of mass ($\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\nabla \cdot (\rho \overrightarrow{u})=0$) we get the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\rho \overrightarrow{u})=-div(\rho \overrightarrow{u})\overrightarrow{u}-\rho(\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \nabla)\overrightarrow{u}-\nabla p+\rho\overrightarrow{b}$$

Could you explain to me how we get the last relation??

Comment: Is $p$ a vector (as indicated by the fact you take its dot product with $\overrightarrow{n}$), or a scalar (as indicated by the fact that you take its gradient)? My guess is that "$p\cdot\overrightarrow{n}$" should be "$p\overrightarrow{n}$"

Comment: @robjohn., $p$ is for pressure; it is a scalar.

Comment: you wiil need to use the mass conservation equation $(\rho u)_t + u \cdot (\rho u) = 0.$

Comment: @abel: yes, I figured that, but $p\cdot\overrightarrow{n}$ makes no sense then

Comment: @robjohn,  you are right. that is the work done by the pressure so it is $\int pn\, dS$

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, your pressure surface integral term is $p\hat{n} dA$, there is no dot product there since the pressure is a scalar. Your last equation is wrong because $u\nabla$ acting on a vector $u$ will not give another vector as written. I'm guessing there is a missing dot product there.

Comment: Isn't the differential form of the mass conservation equation $$\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+\nabla \cdot (\rho \overrightarrow{u})=0$$ ?? @abel

Comment: So, do you mean that it should be as followed?? 

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\rho \overrightarrow{u})=-div(\rho \overrightarrow{u})\overrightarrow{u}-\rho(\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \nabla)\overrightarrow{u}-\nabla p+\rho\overrightarrow{b}$$ @user_of_math

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\rho\vec{u}\right)$, begin with the product rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\rho\vec{u}\right)=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\vec{u}+\rho\frac{\partial\vec{u}}{\partial t}.\tag{1}$$
The first term in (1) is then calculated using the differential (or local) mass balance, since
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = -\nabla\cdot(\rho\vec{u})=-\text{div}(\rho\vec{u}).\tag{2}$$
The second term in (1) is given from
$$\rho\frac{\partial\vec{u}}{\partial t} = -p(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}-\nabla p+\rho\vec{b}.\tag{3}$$
Substituting (2) and (3) into (1) gives the desired conclusion.